# How do I know if images are being cached properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

I'm hosting a Rails app on Heroku and not sure if my static images are being cached or not.  Below are my logs from loading the same image three times.  Are the last two requests being served from the cache?  What does **"stale, invalid, store"** mean?

These are just static assets and I'm not using the asset pipeline in Rails 3.1

```
    2012-01-24T03:37:27+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/offer-new-reward-button.png?1327376077] miss, store
    2012-01-24T03:37:27+00:00 heroku[nginx]: (ip) - - [24/Jan/2012:03:37:27 +0000] "GET /images/offer-new-reward-button.png?1327376077 HTTP/1.1" 200 3692 "-" "curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5" myapp.heroku.com
    2012-01-24T03:37:27+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.heroku.com/images/offer-new-reward-button.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=3692

    2012-01-24T03:37:52+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/offer-new-reward-button.png?1327376077] stale, invalid, store
    2012-01-24T03:37:52+00:00 heroku[nginx]: (ip) - - [24/Jan/2012:03:37:52 +0000] "GET /images/offer-new-reward-button.png?1327376077 HTTP/1.1" 200 3692 "-" "curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5" myapp.heroku.com
    2012-01-24T03:37:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.heroku.com/images/offer-new-reward-button.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=3692

    2012-01-24T03:38:25+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /images/offer-new-reward-button.png?1327376077] stale, invalid, store
    2012-01-24T03:38:25+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.heroku.com/images/offer-new-reward-button.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3692
    2012-01-24T03:38:25+00:00 heroku[nginx]: (ip) - - [24/Jan/2012:03:38:25 +0000] "GET /images/offer-new-reward-button.png?1327376077 HTTP/1.1" 200 3692 "-" "curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5" myapp.heroku.com
```

Answer (score 1):

As you appear to NOT be running on the Cedar stack, your static files should automatically be cached with Varnish.

More info here:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-caching

To test your caching, simply get one of the images and look at the response headers.  You should see the caching headers set here along with a via header from Varnish.